# how to make "uploaded via" link at the bottom of the post to link to user's website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**what I need:** upload photos to user's fan page as a page, using an app for that

**what I have:** my website which does uploading, and a user, who created fan page and application, and that app's id and secret

**what I do:**

1. call `FB.init()` with that appId
2. call `FB.login()` with `manage_pages,publish_stream` permissions - this prompts FB login popup where user is asked to login and then to authenticate the app. As the result I get app access token.
3. Send request to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE` to get extended app token valid for 2 months (and therefore page tokens will be extended as well as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#page_access_token))
4. Send request to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE` to get a list of pages user manages, and let user to choose the page he wants to publish to.
5. That gives me PAGE access token I can use to publish photos to user's FAN page using `/albumId/photos/` API call.

**what is the problem:**

the "via" link in the photo redirects user to MY website (where user has authenticated his app to upload to his page): [image]

that is because I had to ask user to enter my website's URL in app settings, otherwise Facebook login dialog will complain:
[image]

---

**SO MY QUESTIONS ARE:**

1. Am I doing this right? am I missing something probably?
2. If I am - then how can I get that "via" link to link to user's website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding client's website URL as a query string parameter into "Site URL" field in the application settings - and then I need to modify my site's backend to do redirects:

```
http://mysite.com/?redirect=http://client-site.com
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get that "via" link to link to user's website?

Not at all, because this *always* links to the app that was used making a post/upload.

What you could try though is having *your* website redirect when a user is coming to your site from Facebook. Which post/feed story the user is coming from should be passed to your site as parameters; then you’d only have to figure out which user made that post (look it up in your database), and redirect to their homepage.

Comment: well, that's not true - as I said, right now "via" link redirects user to MY website. If I change "Site URL" field in app settings to user's website - then the link will redirect to that website - but in this case FB.Login() call on MY website will fail - saying "invalid website" or something like this.

Comment: Oh but yes, it _is_ true. If you change the site URL for your app, then the via link _still_ goes to your app – which you told Facebook resides at the user’s website location. But that that approach is not feasible, you’ve found out already yourself. So, use the method I suggested instead, if you want a working solution.

Comment: ic what you mean - yes, strictly speaking you are right. However, question still remains the same - are there any workarounds? The one you suggest looks quite complex to me. Thanks!

Comment: that will not work - the link has only app id, it does not have post ID or anything like that in it - so I can't track that. I think I found better solution though. Thanks for helping.